# How can I draw a partial circle with LineRenderer?

Tags: 2d, mathematics, geometry, line-renderer

I'm using the following code, which I found online, to draw a circle with a predefined radius centred on a predefined point in LineRenderer (2D game).

```
string[] natcoords = circleData[i].Split(' ');
        float xcentre = getX(natcoords[1], centrepos);
        float ycentre = getY(natcoords[0], centrepos);
        Vector3 centerpos = new Vector3(xcentre, ycentre, 0f);

        float startWidths = 0.007f;
        float endWidths = 0.007f;
        float fullradius = float.Parse(circleData[i + 1]);
        float radius = fullradius / 6.5f;
        int vertexNumber = 70;


        LineRenderer line = (new GameObject("line")).AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        line.startWidth = startWidths;
        line.endWidth = endWidths;
        line.loop = true;
        float angle = 2 * Mathf.PI / vertexNumber;
        line.positionCount = vertexNumber;
        line.useWorldSpace = true;
        line.material = materialtouse;

        for (int e = 0; e < vertexNumber; e++)
        {
            Matrix4x4 rotationMatrix = new Matrix4x4(new Vector4(Mathf.Cos(angle * e), Mathf.Sin(angle * e), 0, 0),
                                                     new Vector4(-1 * Mathf.Sin(angle * e), Mathf.Cos(angle * e), 0, 0),
                                       new Vector4(0, 0, 1, 0),
                                       new Vector4(0, 0, 0, 1));
            Vector3 initialRelativePosition = new Vector3(0, radius, 0);
           line.SetPosition(e, centerpos + rotationMatrix.MultiplyPoint(initialRelativePosition));

        }
```

What I would like to do is have a separate method that can draw a **partial** circle, with a specified start and end angle relative to the centre. So basically a circle with a gap in it.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It looks like you could adjust the range of values you use with that for loop, no? How have you tried modifying the code so far?